# What is the quantity $\sqrt{\frac{c^2+d^2}{a^2+b^2}}$ of a matrix with determinant one?

Tags: matrices

Suppose that $A \in \mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$ has determinant one,
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I'm currently working on a problem where I obtained a condition on the quantity
$$
\sqrt{\frac{c^2+d^2}{a^2+b^2}}.
$$
I was wondering whether this some known quantity which has a specific meaning. Did somebody encounter this quantity before?

Comment: I think it's the same as $\frac{\sqrt{1 + (ac+bd)^{2}}}{a^{2}+b^{2}},$ but I do not know any way to attach any meaning to the expression,

Comment: Trivial observation: it's the ratio between the norms of the two rows. Intuitively it seems related to the condition number: the larger it is, the further $A$ is from a multiple of an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: No. The matrix with rows equal to $(\cosh\theta ~ \sinh \theta)$ and $(\sinh \theta ~ \cosh\theta)$ can be far from being orthogonal although the ratio of their norm is $1$.